# How to add dummy content in free wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

i addded a wordpress free theme from wordpress.org . now i want to add dummy content of the theme. but i am unable to find the file where it is located.

This is the link of the theme https://wordpress.org/themes/formation/

Please can anybody help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://hu.wordpress.org/plugins/fakerpress/) plugin. It's a dummycontent generator.

Comment: Thnx for help i 'll try

Comment: No problem. If my answer solved your question, don't hesitate to mark it with the green checkmark :)